# Return O365 Teams Meeting Organizer

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams, skype

I've been trying to figure out a way to return Office 365 Teams meeting details. More specifically the creator of a live meeting. Does anyone know if it's possible through Powershell?

Comment: Office 365 can be accessed with Microsoft Graph Api. More details 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into [Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [Calendar event API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) Graph APIs.